# JQuery replace find and replace a certain tag in image src

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html image like below:

```
<img class="post-thumb" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-v4ekzlZEc/YZUZJjVN8tI/AAAAAAAChsA/GSOuME5yUYs_-G3OX1TfwCPcBGAsYHg/s72-w640-h426-c/402.JPG">
```

I want to use JQuery to dynamically change anythig that says "/s72-" with "/s720-"

I have the following code, but my regex in the replace is just wrong as I got that from somehwere online.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var dimension = 720;
var image = $('.post-thumb');
image.attr({src : image.attr('src').replace(/w\B\d{2,4}/,'w' + dimension)});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use directly replace with 's72' like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dimension = 720;
  var image = $('.post-thumb');
  image.attr({
    src: image.attr('src').replace('/s72', '/s' + dimension)
  });
  console.log(image.attr('src'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="post-thumb" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-v4ekzlZEc/YZUZJjVN8tI/AAAAAAAChsA/GSOuME5yUYs_-G3OX1TfwCPcBGAsYHg/s72-w640-h426-c/402.JPG">
```

---

PS: I only considered one instance to modify, if there should be more to modify use `replaceAll`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dimension = 720;
  var image = $('.post-thumb');
  image.attr({
    src: image.attr('src').replaceAll('/s72', '/s' + dimension)
  });
  console.log(image.attr('src'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="post-thumb" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/s72-v4ekzlZEc/YZUZJjVN8tI/AAAAAAAChsA/GSOuME5yUYs_-G3OX1TfwCPcBGAsYHg/s72-w640-h426-c/402.JPG">
```

Reference:

- [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

Comment: `.replace` will only replace the first occurrence in [tag:javascript].  Either use a regex or the (newer) `.replaceAll`

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for pointing this out, I have corrected the answer.

Comment: I just tried the replaceAll but for some reason it replaces all the images with the same image. So for example i can have two images, if I remove the script then two images shows. But when I add the script the images change to the same one. I think it's because all imageins are in the same class="post-thumb"

Comment: You need to use each/forEach

Comment: @JohnRoberts have you resolve the problem? can you acept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the following regex to replace the fixed character,

`/g - will replace more than one occurrence`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var dimension = 720;
  var image = $('.post-thumb');
  image.attr({src : image.attr('src').replace(/\/s2-/g, '/s'+dimension));
});
```

**Using Native JavaScript:**

You don't need jQuery. You can write this in native JS way,

```
var dimension = 720;
var image = document.querySelector('.post-thumb');
if (image) {
    image.setAttribute('src', image.getAttribute('src').replace('s72', 's' + dimension))
    console.log(image.getAttribute('src'));
}
```

If you want code to execute on page load use `onload` or `domcontentloaded` events.